# Where is Spring's @Formatted annotation?

Tags: spring-mvc, formatted

I'm trying to define a custom formatter for my class, but I can't find the @Formatted annotation mentioned in [Spring's documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s06.html):

> 5.6.2 @Formatted
>
> The @Formatted annotation allows you to easily associate a Formatter implementation with one of your classes. To use this feature, simply annotate your class as @Formatted and specify the Formatter implementation to use as the annotation value:
>
> ```
> @Formatted(MoneyFormatter.class)
> public class Money {
> ...
> }
> ```
>
> The example above says "Money objects should be formatted by a MoneyFormatter". With this configuation, whenever a field is of type Money, MoneyFormatter will format the field value.

I'm using maven and IntelliJ, and usually it's able to auto-import the required classes or find the required maven dependency. Neither sarching on mvnbrowser and google for `Formatted` gave any hint.

I can import `org.springframework.format.annotation.*` and `org.springframework.ui.*` but it's not in there.

I'm using Spring 3.*

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at out-of-date documentation (your link is for the 3.0 RC1 release). The [current documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-CustomFormatAnnotations) makes no mention of that annotation.